# Sinch Calling with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, sinch

I'm attempting to make a basic phone call using the Sinch Calling API; however, I keep running into errors. The code I have so far is to simply create the SinchClient object, and then to attempt to make an outbound phone call:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const SinchClient = require('sinch-rtc');

const sinch = new SinchClient({
    applicationKey: '********',
    capabilities: { calling: true }
});

app.post('/sinch', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('testing');
    const callListeners = {
        onCallEstablished: (call) => {
            res.send(call.incomingStreamURL);
        }
    }
    const callClient = sinch.getCallClient();
    const call = callClient.callPhoneNumber('+46000000000');

    call.addEventListener(callListeners);
})

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('listening on port 8080'));
```

Unfortunately, I'm encountering the following error when I attempt to run my app:

```
***-MacBook-Pro:** ***$ node index
/Users/***/Documents/Coding Projects/Borsa/node_modules/sinch- rtc/lib/sinch.node.min.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var PAPI,PUBNUB=require("pubnub").init({}),XMLHttpRequest=require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest,window=window||global,WRTC=require("wrtc"),navigator=navigator||{mediaDevices:{getUserMedia:function(){return!1},userAgent:""}}||{getUserMedia:function(){return!1},userAgent:""}||{mozGetUserMedia:function(){return!1},userAgent:""}||{webkitGetUserMedia:function(){return!1},userAgent:""},btoa=require("btoa"),atob=require("atob"),localStorage=require("localStorage"),SinchTicketGenerator=require("sinch-ticketgen"),Q=require("q"),SinchVersion=require("../VERSION"),ErrorDomain=(SinchTicketGenerator=require("sinch-ticketgen"),{ErrorDomainNone:-1,ErrorDomainNetwork:0,ErrorDomainCapability:1,ErrorDomainSession:2,ErrorDomainApi:3,ErrorDomainOther:4,ErrorDomainSDK:5,ErrorDomainVerification:7}),ErrorCode={NoneNone:0,NetworkConnectionRefused:1e3,NetworkConnectionTimed

TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at new Sinch (/Users/***/Documents/Coding Projects/**/node_modules/sinch-rtc/lib/sinch.node.min.js:1:5078)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/***/Documents/Coding Projects/**/index.js:5:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

This is clearly an issue with the Sinch SDK that's in the current version of the node module; and I can't seem to understand what is causing this indexOf error. I attempted to look into the minified code, and I see the issue is around the userAgent.indexOf code block, but it doesn't make much sense from there.

If I take out the new SinchClient code block, the error no longer appears (I also comment out everything to do with the Sinch code). Anyone else have an issue like this? Any idea why the nodejs module of the Sinch SDK seems to be catered towards code that needs to run on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The Sinch JS library is a client-side library intended for browsers with webrtc and microphone., you cant use that in node server side.